# Fill Between with Multiple Tikzpicture

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween, polarplot

I am using PGFPlots version 1.14 and PGF version 3.0.1a and am having a weird effect with fill between.  The coloring for fill between is appearing in the subsequent graph, not in the graph it was defined in.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
hide axis, 
]
\addplot[domain=0:360, smooth, blue, name path=rose]{cos(2*x)};
\addplot[domain=0:360, smooth, red, name path = circle]{.5};
\addplot[yellow] fill between[of=circle and rose];
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[green] fill between[of=NoPathA and NoPathB];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

with result

[image]

Why isn't the fill happening in the original picture, and why is the fill showing up in the second picture, even when I put in dummy name paths?

Comment: Apparently the problem is caused by `polaraxis`. Although the plot would be different, in `axis` environment everything seems O.K.

Comment: BTW, you could stand to up the number of samples.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the problem is caused by the `polaraxis` when filling between the two plots.

Here is my solution for your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[hide axis]
\begin{scope}[]
\addplot[domain=0:360, smooth, blue, name path=rose]{cos(2*x)};
\addplot[domain=0:360, smooth, red, name path = circle]{.5};
\tikzfillbetween[of=rose and circle]{yellow}
  \end{scope}
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: The scope doesn't appear to be needed.